# How do I recreate this complicated shape?

Tags: modifiers

[image: comparison to my model]

I have a reference for what I want to model, but I'm lacking the problem solving skills necessary to recreate it with reasonable accuracy.

I've looked into using a Boolean modifier within a cylinder to create the platform (with some success,) but it isn't giving me the results I'm looking for. It's just not quite the shape I'm looking for.

I've tried the knife tool and really forcing the issue, but the geometry didn't come out clean. If anything that created more problems.

There's probably a million ways to skin a cat, but what might be one of the most standard ways of recreating this shape?

Blender file attachment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13RJYM3lYtOE-pVZ1VcdqTM4rn5mvo08O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There really isn't a standard way. There are even competing schools of thought on what technique to use. It also matters what you are going to use the shape for.  Background objects can be modeled more simply than 'hero' objects for example.

Comment: select it, Shift-D, move your cursor, click. ;)

Comment: It isn't a complicated shape

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - adding more boolean modifiers seemed to do the trick!

I wasn't aware you can combine the same modifier repeatedly without applying it destructively.